# How to convert string entries in pandas dataframe to integers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The pandas data frame that I was working with has a column with string entries and I wish to convert it to integers.

The column is called `diagnosis` and each row has a value of either `M` or `B`. I wanted to convert all `M` to 1 and all `B` to 0 with the following code

```
for row in data['diagnosis']:
  if row == 'M':
    row = 1
  else:
    row = 0
```

But it does not change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` to do this

```
data['diagnosis'] = data['diagnosis'].map({'M':1,'B':0})
```